# Cant add value in QueryCompletedEventArgs to List

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have loop for FindRoute

```
  List<double> so = new List<double>;
  private void FindRoute(GeoCoordinate[] wp)
     {
             RouteQuery query = new RouteQuery()
             {
                 TravelMode = TravelMode.Driving,
                 Waypoints =  wp

             };
             query.QueryCompleted += route5Query_QueryCompleted;
             query.QueryAsync();

     }
void route5Query_QueryCompleted(object sender, QueryCompletedEventArgs<Route> e)
    {

        Route myroute = null;
        myroute = e.Result;
        so.Add(myroute.LengthInMeters);

    }
```

And this is button click event

```
private void ShortestFindButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    { 
          for (int i = 0; i < ZList.Count(); i++)
          {
              FindRoute(ZList[i]);

          }
          MessageBox.Show(so.Count().ToString());

    }
```

But when i call so.Count() it always 0. What is my problem?
Thanks for help

Comment: Where are you looking at the results?  How do you know that any queries have completed at that point in time?

Comment: i added click event where i call count()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're sending of the query requests and then inspecting the resulting list before any of the queries have had time to respond.  The queries, as the method `QueryAsync` indicates, are *asynchronous*.  They do not wait until the query completes before continuing on.

If you want an easy, effective way of doing something with the results of a bunch of asynchronous operations, the TPL makes this a lot easier than the alternatives.

First we can make a small refactor to `FindRoute` so that it returns a `Task<double>` rather than mutating a list when the query completes:

```
private Task<double> FindRoute(GeoCoordinate[] wp)
{
    RouteQuery query = new RouteQuery()
    {
        TravelMode = TravelMode.Driving,
        Waypoints = wp

    };
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<double>();
    query.QueryCompleted += (s, args) =>
        tcs.TrySetResult(args.Result.LengthInMeters);
    query.QueryAsync();
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Then we can call `Task.WhenAll` on a sequence of these tasks to get a collection of all of the results:

```
private async void ShortestFindButoon_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var so = await Task.WhenAll(
        ZList.Select(coords => FindRoute(coords)));
    MessageBox.Show(so.Count().ToString());
}
```

Comment: So what should i do to fix it

Comment: @user3395782 Don't access the results until all of the queries have completed.